# Inserting JSON data from python into SQL Server

Tags: python, sql, arrays, json, sql-server

I make a call to an API via a Python script to retrieve data. I store this data into a JSON file using:

```
  with open('response.json()', 'w') as outfile:
   json5.dump(response.json(), outfile, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Please find below the contents of the JSON file:

```
 {
query: {
    dimensions: [
        "Products.desc",
        "Products.category",
   ],
    measures: [
        "Products.price",
        "Products.amount",
   ],
    filters: [
        {
            operator: "inDateRange",
            values: [
                "2021-11-12",
            ],
            member: "Products.createdDate",
        },
        {
            operator: "equals",
            values: [
                "Scotland",
            ],
            member: "Products.region",
        },
    ],
    timezone: "UTC",
    order: [],
    timeDimensions: [],
},
data: [
    {
        "Products.desc": "Pens",
        "Products.category": "Stationery",
        "Products.price": "10.15000000",
        "Products.amount": "5",
   },
    {
        "Products.desc": "Bags",
        "Products.category": "Clothing",
        "Products.price": "40.5000000",
        "Products.amount": "10",
    },          
    {
       "Products.desc": "Drink",
       "Products.category": "Foods",
       "Products.price": "15.2000000",
       "Products.amount": "20",
     },
],
lastRefreshTime: "2021-12-15T12:48:10.230Z",
annotation: {
    measures: {
        "Products.price": {
            title: "Products Price",
            shortTitle: "Products Total Price",
            type: "number",
            drillMembers: [],
            drillMembersGrouped: {
                measures: [],
                dimensions: [],
            },
        },
        "Products.amount": {
            title: "Products Amount",
            shortTitle: "Products Total Amount",
            type: "number",
            drillMembers: [],
            drillMembersGrouped: {
                measures: [],
                dimensions: [],
            },
         },
    },
    dimensions: {
        "Products.desc": {
            title: "Products description",
            shortTitle: "Desc",
            type: "string",
        },
        "Products.category": {
            title: "Products category",
            shortTitle: "Category",
            type: "string",
        },
      
     segments: {},
    timeDimensions: {},
},
slowQuery: false,
```

}

I have tried extracting the values onto a table in SQL Server but to no avail.

```
DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET 
(BULK N'[Folder path]', SINGLE_CLOB) 
AS j

SELECT ISJSON(@JSON) AS IsValidJson;
```

It is not recognising this as valid JSON and getting the error message "JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'q' is found at position 7."

All I would like is to extract only the values in the data array into a table as seen below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUqoy.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: Please edit the question, and provide the JSON in question in its entirety. It looks truncated.

Comment: All JSON keys should be surrounded by double quotes.

Comment: Apologies for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I store this data into a JSON file using:

No, you are not doing that.  You are storing the data into a [JSON5](https://json5.org/) file instead.

If you want to store data into a JSON file, use the `json` module, not the `json5` module:

```py
  with open('response.json()', 'w') as outfile:
   json.dump(response.json(), outfile, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am using PyCharm and only had JSON5 package available. I was able to just use JSON on the script. Thanks again!